# List of useful Add-Ins for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

What are the best Add-Ins for ArcCatalog and ArcMap v10?

[XRay for ArcGIS 10](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=596204091a9147f9b609a6537a51d0d1) is very useful, what else is out there?

Comment: This question is not answerable as stated, because "best" will be in the eye of the user.  Please consider rephrasing it in a more constructive manner.  For example, consider specifying a *purpose* to the add-in and inquiring about, say, how people *identify* good add-ins and what *criteria* they use to evaluate them.  This will provide answers that are of more than merely transient interest to a subcommunity.

Answer (score 6):

It might be poor form to post my own AddIns, but I'm doing it anyway(*they are free and I don't post these in ESRI galleries*).

I wrote an AddIn with a single button(command) that fires up the browser to google streetview at the same extent as the ArcMap extent([avi movie](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cumminsjp/component-handbook-contains-the-absent-appendix/GoogleStreetView.avi)). This is the one that my users ask for the most:
[GoogleStreetView.esriAddIn](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cumminsjp/component-handbook-contains-the-absent-appendix/GoogleStreetView.esriAddIn)

Select stacked features: [SelectStackedFeatures.esriAddIn](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cumminsjp/component-handbook-contains-the-absent-appendix/SelectStackedFeatures.esriAddIn). A button that make a feature selection of any stacked features of a highlighted feature layer.  Sorry, no avi movie for this one.

I also have an AddIn that does automatic timestamping and attribution. From my ideas.arcgis.com comment on timestamping:

> I wrote an AddIn that does a lot of
>   this (right around the same time as
>   Infrastructure Editing Template for
>   ArcGIS 10 was released) , but I
>   haven't gotten around to writing any
>   documentation for it.
>
> There is a toggle button, so you can
>   disable it.
>
> It's configurable with an XML file (
>   global or a featureclass specific
>   replacement value template).
>
> Built in:
>   {MachineName}
>   {UserName}
>   {DomainName}
>   {NOW}
>   {WKB} (Well-known binary)
>   {GEOHASH} (geohash point features only).
>   {e:any-environment-variable}
>
> On the TODO list:
>   {WKT}
>   {XCOORD}
>   {YCOORD}
>   {ZCOORD}
>
> Download Location:
>   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1156285/EditorTrack.esriAddIn

Answer (score 5):

**XTools pro**

http://www.xtoolspro.com/

> "More than 80 tools and functions for spatial analysis, shape
>   conversions and table management in ArcGIS"

stems back to ArcView 3.2

Version 12.2 is compatible with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.0, 10.1, 10.2.x, 10.3.x and 10.4.

https://xtools.pro/en/resources/xtools-pro-121-released/

(not affiliated with xtools)

Comment: XTools Pro only took the name from the old XTools on ArcView.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the new marketplace with a filter on desktop applications.
There are quite a few very useful addins in this list Take a look at the new (what3words geocoder/encoder) and an even larger list without the desktop filter:

[Esri marketplace Desktop applications](https://marketplace.arcgis.com/search.html#t=apps&platform=Application)

I have installed geotagger, presentation, and diagrammer. There are so many to try!

[add-ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/search/?do=search&collection=blogs&filter=0&lg=en&q=addin&submit=)

[Prototype Lab](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/)

[Diagrammer](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/04/01/esri-tv/)

[Presentation](http://blogs.esri.com/dev/blogs/apl/archive/2010/07/16/presentation-addin-for-arcgis-desktop-10.aspx)

[No Cost Add ons](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/extensions)

Answer (score 1):

The first plugin I always used to get was Mapbook but that functionality now comes as part of ArcGIS 10.x's Data Driven Pages, and it is better in some ways.

Also used to get Hawths and Iankos, but now most of that stuff has been added as geoprocessing tools, so I think plugins play a smaller role now than in the past.

Comment: I think custom ArcMap tools, in general, show Esri what the users want and then you see it a few releases later.  `Go To XY` is one that comes to mind--I think everyone had their own version of that until Esri added it to ArcMap in 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Golden Software (disclaimer, I work here) just released [Raster Tools](http://www.goldensoftware.com/products/rastertools). This add-in currently works on ArcMap 10.3 (let us know if you'd like it developed for other versions).

Raster Tools expands the abilities of ArcMap when creating raster datasets from regularly and irregularly spaced XYZ data. It's ideal for users requiring more interpolation methods, more accurate algorithms, and more control over all interpolation parameters.

- Interpolation methods include Kriging, Inverse Distance, Minimum Curvature, Polynomial Regression, Triangulation with Linear Interpolation, Nearest Neighbor, Modified Shepard’s Method, Radial Basis Function, Natural Neighbor, Moving Average, Data Metrics, and Local Polynomial.
- Interpolation parameters include search controls to determine which data points are considered during the interpolation operation, the ability to use breaklines and faults during the interpolation calculation, and anisotropy settings to apply preferential weighting along a specified direction.

Free trial: http://www.goldensoftware.com/rastertools/trial